# Why is my while loop not working as i expected?

Tags: python

so I'm writing this code for a game I'm working on. But I can't figure out what i did wrong. When I run this code, even if I do type in the right number it still wrong. I think there's something error with my while loop. Can anybody help me out a bit?Will be really appreciated By the way I am very new to python.

The code are as following:

```
Guess_Count = 0
Guess_Limit = 7
Store_Guess_Nam = []
Guess_Nam = int()
import random
Nam = list(range(1, 25))
Random_Nam = random.choice(Nam)
print (Random_Nam)
while Guess_Count < Guess_Limit:
    if Guess_Nam < Random_Nam:
        Guess_Nam = int(input("Enter Number: "))
        print("Number too small.")
        Guess_Count += 1
    elif Guess_Nam > Random_Nam:
        Guess_Nam = int(input("Enter Number: "))
        print("Number too big.")
        Guess_Count += 1
    elif Guess_Nam == Random_Nam:
        Guess_Nam = int(input("Enter Number: "))
        print("Correct")
        break
else:
    print("Out of guess.")
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: When I run this, I get the following error:Enter Number: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    Guess_Nam = int(input("Enter Number: "))
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is:

1. Check the user input. (which is 0 at the beginning)
2. Ask a new user input.
3. Print the information of the first user input.

But what you probaly want to do is:

1. Check the unser input.
2. Print the information of the user input.
3. Ask a new user input.
4. And also don't ask a new user input if it is correct.

Your code should look like this:

```py
while Guess_Count < Guess_Limit:
    if Guess_Nam < Random_Nam:
        print("Number too small.")
        Guess_Nam = int(input("Enter Number: "))
        Guess_Count += 1
    elif Guess_Nam > Random_Nam:
        print("Number too big.")
        Guess_Nam = int(input("Enter Number: "))
        Guess_Count += 1
    elif Guess_Nam == Random_Nam:
        print("Correct")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You are evaluating the input before you are requesting it. Modify your loop to do this:

1. Get the input
2. Evaluate the input

It should look like this:

```
while Guess_Count < Guess_Limit:
    Guess_Nam = int(input("Enter Number: "))
    if Guess_Nam < Random_Nam:
        print("Number too small.")
        Guess_Count += 1
    elif Guess_Nam > Random_Nam:
        print("Number too big.")
        Guess_Count += 1
    elif Guess_Nam == Random_Nam:
        print("Correct")
        break
```